# Need to expand / collapse summary of a play and connect two ID's using switch

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a webpage that has a list of six Shakespeare plays, and when you click on the title of a play, the summary appears. This is the first play, as an example:

```
<div class="playheader" id="play1">
    <h3>Romeo and Juliet</h3>
</div>
<div class="summary" id="sum1">
    <p>Stupid teenagers fall in love and die.</p>
</div>
```

I then used this FOR loop to make it so that clicking on a title toggles the summary. I know that this part is correct:

```
window.onload = initPlaySelector;
function initPlaySelector() {
    var playheaders = document.getElementsByClassName("playheader"); 
    for (i=0; i<playheaders.length; i++) { 
    playheaders[i].onclick = togglePlotSum; 
}    
}
```

My problem is getting the list to expand. The assignment instructions say that I should have 6 SWITCH statement cases inside the function that connect the ID of the title (play1) to the ID of the summary (sum1). I do not understand how I am supposed to connect these two ID's and use them in a switch case. This is what I have so far, with just one case done. What am I doing wrong?

```
function togglePlotSum() {
    alert("hello");
    var x = this.id // current object is play1/play2/etc. 
switch (x) {
    case 'play1':
    var summary = document.getElementById('sum1');
    if ( summary.style.display == "none" ) {
    summary.style.display = "block";
 }
    else if ( summary.style.display == "block" ) {
    summary.style.display = "none";
 }            
    break;
}
}
```

Please do not tell me to use JQuery, as I don't know how. I just don't know what my assignment means when it says that I need to "make a connection" between play1 and sum1.

Comment: hi, this switch case works fine?

Comment: what you are doing seems to be fine.. simply add the other 5 cases..

Answer (score 0):

```
function togglePlotSum() {
 var id = this.id // current object is play1/play2/etc. 
 switch (id) {
  case 'play1':
    showOrHide('sum1');           
    break;
  case 'play2':
    showOrHide('sum2');       
    break;
  case 'play3':
    showOrHide('sum3');          
    break;
  case 'play4':
    showOrHide('sum4');           
    break;
  case 'play5':
    showOrHide('sum5');        
    break;
  case 'play6':
    showOrHide('sum6');          
    break;
 }
}
function showOrHide(id){
 var summary = document.getElementById(id);
    if (summary.style.display == "none") {
     summary.style.display = "block";
    }
    else if ( summary.style.display == "block" ) {
    summary.style.display = "none";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, guys. I am not going to post my full code because some people in my class are still doing the assignment. However, I figured out that what my instructor was trying to hint at is that I should use the "replace" function to replace "play" with "sum" so that "play1" becomes "sum1."

Answer (score -1):

I hope, it should work

```
<div class="playheader" id="play_1">
    <h3>Romeo and Juliet</h3>
</div>
<div class="summary" id="sum_1">
    <p>Stupid teenagers fall in love and die.</p>
</div>
```

and javascript code goes here

```
initPlaySelector();

function initPlaySelector() {
    var playheaders = document.getElementsByClassName("playheader"); 
    for (i=0; i<playheaders.length; i++) { 
    playheaders[i].onclick = togglePlotSum; 
}    
} 





 function togglePlotSum() {

        var x = this.id // current object is play1/play2/etc. 
        id=x.split('_').pop(); // it will give the number after underscore

        var summary = document.getElementById("sum_"+id);
        if ( summary.style.display == "none" ) {
        summary.style.display = "block";
     }
        else if ( summary.style.display == "block" ) {
        summary.style.display = "none";
     }
```

Comment: What about other cases..?

Comment: what is other cases?, we dont need switch case anymore

Comment: well that's according to your edit. your first answer had a switch with single case. now you're missing " I am supposed to connect these two ID's and use them in a switch case" - this part.

Comment: why do you need switch case,if you can do what you want without switch case

Comment: read the question properly. it's an assignment. probably for learning `switch` statement or something.

Comment: i dont know,what i am giving is optimal soultion. that's it

Comment: a solution is not optimal if it doesn't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: that, he(user3710004) would decide

Comment: it's already mentioned clearly in the question. **The assignment instructions say that I should have 6 SWITCH statement cases inside the function that connect the ID.** you should at least read the question properly before answering.